# Prove that functions with the same graph are equal to each other (Analysis 1 by Terence Tao - Exercise: 3.5.10)

Tags: functions, solution-verification

*This is a request to review the below proofs. Thanks for your time! :)*

**Proof (1) :**

> 1. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function, define the *graph* of $f$ to be
>    the subset of $X \times Y$ defined by $\{ (x, f(x): x \in X \}$.
>    Show that two functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $f': X \rightarrow Y$ are equal if and only if they have the same graph.

\begin{align}
&\color{blue}{\text{Suppose if, } \ \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in X  \} = \{ (x, f'(x)) : x \in X  \}}
\\
\\
&\implies (m, n) \in \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in X  \} \iff (m, n) \in \{ (x, f'(x)) : x \in X  \}
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}((m, n) = (x, f(x)) \iff (m, n) = (x, f'(x))\color{red})
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}(m = x \ \land \ n = f(x) \iff m = x \ \land \ n = f'(x) \color{red})
\\
\\
&\text{($m = x \iff m = x$ is redundant above. So, safely ignoring it in the next step)}
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}( n = f(x) \iff n = f'(x) \color{red})
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}( f(x) = f'(x) \color{red})
\\
\\
&\text{Since $f$ & $f'$ has same domain, range and $\forall x \in X \color{red}(f(x) = f'(x)\color{red})$, we have:}
\\
\\
&\implies f = f' .
\\
\\
\\
&\color{blue}{\text{Suppose if, } \ f = f'}
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}( f(x) = f'(x) \color{red})
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}( x = x \land f(x) = f'(x) \color{red})
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}( (x, f(x)) = (x, f'(x)) \color{red})
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X \ \color{red}((m, n) = (x, f(x)) \iff (m, n) = (x, f'(x))\color{red})
\\
\\
&\implies (m, n) \in \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in X  \} \iff (m, n) \in \{ (x, f'(x)) : x \in X  \}
\\
\\
&\implies \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in X  \} = \{ (x, f'(x)) : x \in X  \}.
\end{align}

**Proof (2) :**

> 2. Conversely, if $G$ is any subset of $X \times Y$ with the property that for each $x \in X$, the set $\{ y \in Y: (x, y) \in G \}$ has
>    exactly one element (or in other words, $G$ obeys the *vertical line
>    test*), show that there is exactly one function $f: X \rightarrow Y$
>    whose graph is equal to $G$.

\begin{align}
&\color{blue}{\text{Show that there} \ \textit{exists} \ \text{a function $f: X \to Y$ with graph $G$}}
\\
\\
&\text{We know that, A map $\phi: A \to B$ is a relation such that,}
\\
&\text{$\forall a \in A: \exists! b \in B\color{orange}{: \phi(a, b)}$ where $\phi(a) := b$}
\\
\\
&\text{Given that G has the property, $\forall x \in X: \exists! y \in \{ y' \in Y: (x, y') \in G \}$}
\\
\\
&\implies \forall x \in X: \exists!y \in Y\color{orange}{: (x, y) \in G}
\\
\\
&\text{We can define $f$ under $P$ where,}
\\
&\text{$\forall x \in X:  \exists! y \in Y$}\color{orange}{: 
 P(x,y)} \ \text{where} \ P(x, y) := (x, y) \in G
\\
\\
&\text{Now the graph of $f = \{(x, f(x)): x \in X \}$}
\\
\\
&\implies (x,y) \in \{ (x, f(x)): x \in X \} \iff P(x, y)
\\
\\
&\implies (x,y) \in \{ (x, f(x)): x \in X \} \iff (x, y) \in G
\\
\\
&\text{Hence, the graph of function $f = G$.}
\\
\\
\\
&\color{blue}{\text{Show the} \ \textit{uniqueness} \ \text{of function $f: X \to Y$ with graph $G$}}
\\
\\
&\text{Let's say that there's another function $f': X \to Y \ \text{with graph} \ G$}
\\
\\
&\text{From (1), we know that,}
\\
&\text{"two functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $f': X \rightarrow Y$ are equal if and only if they have the same graph"}
\\
\\
&\text{Therefore, $f$ and $f'$ have same graph $G \implies f = f'$}
\\
\\
&\text{$f$ is unique.}
\\
\\
\\
&\text{There exists exactly one function $f: X \to Y$ whose graph is equal to $G$.}
\end{align}

I'd stumbled on this problem and trying to prove this for quite a while. Please let me know if this looks good and also where I can improve. Thanks again!

Comment: everything seems ok to me, but i think your language could be clearer on showing existence IMO (again, I'd probably still give you full points if this was a test), you just need to asign the unique element in the vertical set and show that it defines a function with that graph.

Comment: @alosc I see your point. Thanks for the suggestion!